# Javascript Decimal to Binary - 64 bit

Tags: javascript, binary, decimal

The binary for the decimal `-805306368` is:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111 11010000000000000000000000000000
```

However, in Javascript I get the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/FjWwf/):

```js
var str = parseInt(-805306368).toString(2);
document.write(str);
```

```
-110000000000000000000000000000
```

Can anyone explain how to parse the 64 bit binary string from this decimal?

Comment: There's a little semantic funny business in your question. `-805306368` in base 10 is exactly what you're getting: `-110000000000000000000000000000` in base 2.  What you're looking for is the two's-complement representation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript does not use the two's-complement representation, it uses the hyphen `-` character in front of the string to represent negative numbers. That's because two's-complement representation requires to know the length of bits. When turning a two's-complement number with a certain number of bits into one with more bits (e.g., when copying from a one-byte variable to a two-byte variable), the most-significant bit must be repeated in all the extra bits.

To get the expected result, you could invert each bit but it doesn't provide the result we want:

```
>>> (~-805306368).toString(2)
"101111111111111111111111111111"
```

Yet, JavaScript does all binary operations on 32-bit integers, so this won't work for bigger (or smaller) numbers and at least will be very confusing. So, you would need to implement your own formatting algorithm.

```
// example of 32-bit-conversion:
>>> (~parseInt("1111111111111111111111111111111",2)).toString(2)
"-10000000000000000000000000000000"
>>> (~parseInt("11111111111111111111111111111111",2)).toString(2)
"0"
```

My Implementation:

```js
function get64binary(int) {
  if (int >= 0)
    return int
      .toString(2)
      .padStart(64, "0");
  else
    return (-int - 1)
      .toString(2)
      .replace(/[01]/g, d => +!+d) // hehe: inverts each char
      .padStart(64, "1");
}

console.log(get64binary(805306368))
console.log(get64binary(-805306368))
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was after. Thanks.

Comment: I've just realised the same. What I expect to be returned is "11010000000000000000000000000000" (the first 32 bits)

Comment: Ok, any pointers on implementing my own formatting algorithm - or an example in another language I can use for guidance?

Comment: Perfect, your function works great. Thanks very much for your help, if Carlsberg did answers.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parseInt()` again. It has an optional second parameter, that enables you to specify the radix (or base) of the number in the string you are trying to parse.

Such as: `parseInt("-110000000000000000000000000000", 2) // gives -805306368`