# JavaScript Base10 to Base2 Function

Tags: javascript, html

The javascript is supposed to convert the input into base2 and display it in the output. I'm confused at why the output"o" is the the exact same as the input"num".
I don't understand why this won't work. I know that the data is being passed correctly because if I put simple math in the function, then the output is fine. However, when I try to put the conversion in, it will not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Base Converter</title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <script>
        function Dec2Bin(val)
        {
            var num = val;
            var n = num.toString(2);
            convert.o.value = n;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <div class="banner"> <!--banner area-->
        Convert from base 10 to base 2
    </div>
    <div class="body"> <!--function area-->
        Please choose a number between 1 and 1,024

        <form name="convert" class="alignment">
            <input type="number" name="num">
            <input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="Dec2Bin(num.value)">
            <output name="o"></output>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `int` never changes, so it's going to be an infinite loop. Also, you can [change bases using `parseInt() and toString()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337419/how-do-you-convert-numbers-between-different-bases-in-javascript).

Comment: `function ConvertToB2(int) {return int.toString(2)}`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek , I've used toString() and rather than the output display the number in a different base, it displays the same number that was put in. I've edited the code which is above. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: @NathanThompson Yes, it's because the value of `val` is a string, making `num` a string. `.toString(2)` needs to be done on an number so you just need to convert it to one. I've added that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the value of `num` is a string. So doing `toString` on a string isn't going to do anything. You simply need to change `num` to a number. You can do this by either doing `var num = +val` or `var num = parseInt(val)`:

```js
function Dec2Bin(val)
{
    var num = +val;
    var n = num.toString(2);
    convert.o.value = n;
}
```

```html
        <form name="convert" class="alignment">
            <input type="number" name="num">
            <input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="Dec2Bin(num.value)">
            <output name="o" value=""></output>
        </form>
```

*Note:* Be careful on relying on your `name` items in your DOM to be global data. As it can cause problems with multiple items with the same name or other browsers. You may want to assign an `id` instead and use `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: Can't handle negative number

Comment: @AderemiDayo Yes, this is due to how `.toString()` was implemented on negatives. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155592/negative-numbers-to-binary-string-in-javascript). For this question specifically the user is only dealing with positive integers, and is a correction to their approach.

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop, you loop while `int > 0`, but `int` never changes.  Thus, it will loop forever (or 0 times).

Also, `int` is technically a reserved word in JavaScript, so you should avoid using it.  Something like `num` would be appropriate.