# Confusion with left-shift operator

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I am trying to create a 32-bit bitmask in JS. However, I don't understand what's happening here:

```
$ node
> const num = Math.pow(2, 31) - 1
undefined
> num
2147483647

# So far, so good
> num.toString(2)
'1111111111111111111111111111111'
> num.toString(2).length
31

# According to MDN, the left-shift operator does:
# "Excess bits shifted off to the left are discarded. 
#    Zero bits are shifted in from the right."
# But that's not what we see here. Instead, it seems to be wrapping.
> num << 1
-2
> (num << 1).toString(2)
'-10'
```

According to my understanding of [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_shift_operators), I'd expect to have a bitmask of 31 `1`s followed by 1 `0`. Instead, I get `-10`. What's going on here?

Comment: this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155592/negative-numbers-to-binary-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Javascript doesn't have `Integer`, but bitwise operators only make sense on `Integer`.

So before bitwise operators, javascript will apply `ToInt32(val)` to your num.

For "Signed 32 bits Integer", the top bit represents 'signed'.

Finally your num overflow the 'signed bit'.

My English is poor, you can check ECMAScript's Language Specification.

Answer (score 2):

It is not wrapping. It is exactly working as the documentation you've linked. In your linked documentation, it says:

> The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format.

Your `num` is `2147483647`, and this number in two's complement format is:

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

After left shifting `num` by 1, it becomes:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
```

The above 32-bit two's complement value is `-2` in decimal number. Hence, you get:

```
> num
2147483647
> num << 1
-2
```

If you call `toString(2)` with a negative decimal number `-2`, it follows some special rule of [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString#Description). What it does is:

1. Take the magitude of the decimal. (`-2` => `2`)
2. Convert the decimal to base-2 string representation. (`2` => `'10'`)
3. Put the minus sign in front. (`'10'` => `'-10'`)

Therefore, you get:

```
> (num << 1).toString(2)
> -10
```

You also get:

```
> (-2).toString(2)
> -10
```

Answer (score 1):

*Today I check your question again then know I misunderstand your main point yesterday.*

*This is your main point:
" I'd expect to have a bitmask of 31 `1`s followed by 1 `0`. Instead, I get -10."*

Because [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

**A negative number doesn't express value directly.**

```
let num=Math.pow(2,31)-1
//num in memory=> 0111111111111111111111111111111
//                ^ 
//                |
//            signed bit
//This number is positive, so
//nothing to do=> 0111111111111111111111111111111

num = num<<1
//num in memory=> 1111111111111111111111111111110
//                ^ 
//                |
//            signed bit
//This number is negative, so flip then add 1
//flip         => 1000000000000000000000000000001
//add 1        => 1000000000000000000000000000010 => '-10'
```