# Bitwise operations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I know that numbers in JavaScript are stored in IEEE-754 format. But when we use integers, particularly bitwise operators, they're represented as two's complement with 32 bits.

So `-1` would be `0xFFFFFFFF`. But `(-1).toString(2)` is `-1`. And `-1 >>> 31` is 1, that's right, but `-1 >>> 32` must be `0`, however it's `4294967295`. And `-1 << 32` must be `0`, but it is `-1`.

Why do bitwise operations work in this way? And `toString()` shows number with sign `-`, why this minus is not in sign bit? Also why `-1 >> 0` is `-1`, but `-1 >>> 0` is `4294967295`? I know what is the difference between `>>` and `>>>`, but the second operand is `0`, so I can't understand why these operations work in different ways.

Comment: There's a [good discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155592/negative-numbers-to-binary-string-in-javascript)

Comment: MDN has good documentation on Bitwise operators in a JavaScript environment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: @DanielLowman I have already read it. But I still don't understand why -1 >>> 32 is not 0? We shift it 32 times and add 32 zeros, so it should be 0

Answer (score 3):

[Difference between >>> and >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and)

> In an arithmetic shift, the sign bit is extended to preserve the
>   signedness of the number.

`-1` in `8 bit` is `11111111` `-2` is `11111110` ...

This is handled like that because if you count to the highest possible number +1, the lowest possible number will be shown (`8 bit: 01111111 +1 = 10000000`), Thats why `111111111` is `-1`

> Logical right shift, however, does not care that the value could
>   possibly represent a signed number; it simply moves everything to the
>   right and fills in from the left with 0s.

so here, `-1 >>>` pushes the `11111111` one to the right so the "-" sign gets lost and the highest positive number `0111111` (in `8 bit`) is shown

Also the reason why -1 >> 0 equals -1 is because 11111111 >> 0 does literally add nothing while -1 >>> 0 still moves everything and fills the left bits with 0, each step you raise this "0" will half the value until 0. You can try -1 >>> 31 to see it gets 1

Comment: Yes, I know. But -1 is 0xFFFFFFFF (or 32 `1`), so -1 >>> 32 sould be 0, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, when you >>> with the amount of bits used, it just restarts the process like it would be >>> 0 again, 33 halfs it again and so on

Comment: Oh, I realize. So when we do any N-bits shift and N >= 32, it will be equal to (N % 32)-bits shift?

Comment: yeah exactly :)

Comment: I'm not sure about JavaScript, but in C, shifting by more bits than the size of CPU registers is *undefined behavior*. Since C bitshift instructions translates into CPU assembly instructions, it becomes hardware-dependent. For example, Intel x86 `shr` / `shl` instructions use only 5 least significant bits of argument on 32bit CPU, or 6 LSBs on 64bit. That's why you get `% 32` behavior (`2 ^ 5 = 32`). However, It doesn't mean that other CPUs (arm, ppc, mibs, etc.) will do the same (maybe they will, but it is not guaranteed).