# convert string to numeric literals ( javascript )

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

```
console.log("0b111" ^ "0b001"); // 6
console.log(0b111 ^ 0b001); // 6
```

Though I can do this, is there any way to convert "0b111" to numeric literals 0b111 ?
thanks.

Comment: Remove the quotes like you've done or use `parseInt("0b111".slice(2), 2)` if you need to do it programmatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert binary representation of number from string to integer number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103487/how-to-convert-binary-representation-of-number-from-string-to-integer-number-in)

Comment: ```const toBinaryFormat = (n) => `0b${n.toString(2)}` ```, and then  `toBinaryFormat(6) ==> "0b110"`.

Comment: thanks, but parseInt("0b111".slice(2), 2) will return 7 which is decimal, not a binary literal

Comment: @justin87qq if you want it to "appear" as a "binary literal" in the console like a RegEx literal does, that is not how numbers work and it is not possible

Comment: Scott's function would return string  which is not a numeric literal

Comment: console.log(typeof toBinaryFormat(6)); // string

Comment: console.log(typeof 0b110); // number

Comment: "`numeric` literal" is "`6`".  that is how console displays `number`s.  \x0001 and 0b111 are syntax representations of a `number`.  what you are trying to ask for isn't possible and doesn't really make sense

Comment: thank you, I got it :D

Comment: As far as the code is concerned, all numeric values are ultimately binary. How the console displays it is irrelevant for calculation purposes, and if you want to display it a certain way on the screen you'll have to use a string for that.