# Javascript Tilde & Two's complement 

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

[Two's complement method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) -  generates `-(x + 1)`.

for example  when JavaScript encounters the Tilde he uses this method:

```
~5 = -(5+1) = -6.
```

Fine - lets go deeper.

Now lets talk about the Two's complement method.

```
5        = 0000 0101
Flip     = 1111 1010
add one  = 1111 1011
```

so `1111 1011` is `-5`.

how ?

again : flip :

```
0000 0100
```

add one :

```
0000 0101
```

And so it was `-5`.

So how does this settle with  `~5=-6` ?

where this `-6` came from ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: ~ operator is bitwise NOT. so the expected result.

Comment: Twos complement
~5 + 2

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, you need to realize that `~` is the bitwise flip operator, which is not the same as the negate operator `-`. `~` does only the bitwise flipping, but the negate operator `-` does bitwise flipping and add one (for integers).

As you've explained, if yo want to go from a postive number `n` to `-n` using the two complement method you bitwise flip/not n and add 1. ~n is just the bit-wise not meaning that `~n=-n-1`.

For instance:

```
5               = 0000 0101
Flipped (~5)    = 1111 1010
```

So, which number does `1111 1010` represent? Since the first digit is a 1 we know it's a negative value. To find which value, do

```
-(flip(1111 1010) + 1) =
-(0000 0101 + 1)
-(0000 0110) =
-6
```

Comment: i didnt see any `00000110` in any of my calculations

Comment: @RoyiNamir - because you have not even looked at -6... Your sample is around figuring two's complement of 5, which is unrelated (to extent) to result of inverting each bit of 5.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I've updated my answer with some full calculations. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 11):

`~5 = -(5 + 1) = -6`

so far so good. However, `~` is not the two's complement, it's the binary inversion operator.

```
5     = 0000 0101
flip  : 1111 1010
```

which is -6

does that make it clear?

Comment: but after the flip we should add 1...no ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir if you add 1 after the flip, you get the two's complement to 5, which is -5. if that's what you want, then yes.

Answer (score 4):

`~` is the Bitwise NOT operator (only inverts the bits of its operand).

For a positive number `n`,

```
~n + 1 = -n
```

Comment: indeed  `-n=~n+1`,  or `~n + 1 = -n`    'cos ~n is just 1s complement.

Answer (score 2):

> [Two's complement method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) -  generates `-(x + 1)`.

Simply put, two's complement does not generate `-(x + 1)`. One's complement does (i.e., ~ / bitwise NOT / flipping the bits).

Two's compliment (flip the bits, add 1) is the ([`-0` averse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Representations)) operation/encoding we use to express a negative number in pure bits (and derive it therefrom). Two's complement of `x` will generate `-x`.

`~5` is nothing more than flipping the bits `0000 0101` to `1111 1010`.

To determine the value of `1111 1010`, we flip back to `0000 0101` and add 1: `0000 0110 (-6)`.

Comment: this is the correct answer...I thought the same when I read all of the other wrong definitions of two complement

Answer (score 0):

Tild(~) -

it is just flip(n). I.e. ~5 = flip(5). In java script numbers are always 64 bit signed. let us take Just 8 bit for reference,

```
 5==> 0000 0101 
~5 ==> filp(0000 0101)
~5 ==> 1111 1010 ==> -6
```

2' complement -

It's filp(n) + 1.

```
5 ==> 0000 0101
2's complement of 5 ==> flip(0000 0101) + 0000 0001
2's complement of 5 ==> 1111 1010 + 000 0001
2's complement of 5 ==> 1111 1011
```

Comment: The [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) says that `~` converts the integer to 32-bit, discarding the more significant digits. The largest number I've found where `~x === -x -1` is `2**31 - 1`, which seems to bear that out.

Answer (score 0):

5        = 0000 0101

Flip     = 1111 1010

conversion break down 1111 1010

```
0 x 2^0 = 0
1 x 2^1 = 2
0 x 2^2 = 0
1 x 2^3 = 8
1 x 2^4 = 16
1 x 2^5 = 32
1 x 2^6 = 64
- 1 x 2^7 = -128
```

So -128+64+32+16+8+0+2+0 = -6