# confusion of negation output of an int in java

Tags: java

I have a int
`a=255=>1111 1111` after negating i.e `~a=10000 0000=>-64`
isnt it suposed to be `0000 0000=>0`
basically want to `~255 to 0` like in 8 bit binary format i.e
`1111 1111 to 0000 0000` with out making it negative.

Comment: please show us your code. how are you negating?

Comment: also: an integer has 4 bytes

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575520/bitwise-negation-gives-unexpected-result

Comment: You use `-` to negate (swap positive number for the same negative), and `~` to invert (flip all the bits). They are very similar, but not the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `a` is probably of type int, which in Java takes up 4 bytes. So what you're getting is:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000
```

You should just mask the result, if you know that you're always going to work with 8 bits:

```
int b = ~a ^ 0xFF;
```

Comment: thanks i hadnt known aboout masking int objects.