# In javascript what is the difference between operator '~' and '!'

Tags: javascript

I am out of theories, i don't know what else to say.

So far i always thought that both changed the value to false.

But, !, changes to true/false.

While, ~ , changes to negative number with 1 less so 2 become -3. Why and how.

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12337406/390819).

Comment: question: how do you know that 00000000000000000000000000001001 is 9.Why there are 32 bits, is it only javascript related?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: You clearly haven't clicked the [link](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.8) in my answer (or the one provided by Praveen): *"The production UnaryExpression : `~` UnaryExpression is evaluated as follows: 1. Let `expr` be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression. 2. Let oldValue be **`ToInt32(GetValue(expr)).`**
3. Return the result of applying bitwise complement to `oldValue`. The result is a **signed 32-bit integer**."*

Comment: oh thanks i didn't see your answer than...:D

Answer (score 1):

**~ (Bitwise NOT)**

Performs the NOT operator on each bit. NOT a yields the inverted value (a.k.a. one’s complement) of a. The truth table for the NOT operation is:

```
a   NOT a
0   1
1   0
```

**Example**

```
9 = 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
               --------------------------------
~9 = 11111111111111111111111111110110 (base 2) = -10 (base 10)
```

Answer sourced from [The tilde `~` operator in JavaScript](http://www.javascriptturnsmeon.com/the-tilde-operator-in-javascript/).

Comment: @MuhammadUmer When you are doing bitwise operations and not boolean operations! :)

Comment: @MuhammadUmer common case is to unset nth bit in an integer: `value & ~(1 << n)` the value will have nth bit unset (0-based indexing from the right)

Comment: man bitwise whole thing is beyond me..I did never get the whole base 2 to base 10 thing down ever.

Answer (score 0):

`!` is a [logical operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9), its result is either `true` or `false`, while `~` is a [bitwise](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.8) operator.

If you don't understand why `~number` is `-number - 1` have a look at [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Two%27s_complement&oldid=560696646).

> I am out of theories, i don't know what else to say.

In this case have a look at the [language's documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/).

Answer (score 0):

! is a boolean operator, it negates the result of a boolean expression.

~ on the other side is the bitwise not operator, which basically means, it flips all the bits in your operand, say, -1 which is represented by all 1 bits to 0 (which means 0 bits are set).