# JS: Why is ~10 (binary, ~1010) = -11 (binary, -1011)?

Tags: javascript, binary, bitwise-operators, signed, twos-complement

In Javascript, if I do the bitwise NOT operation on the *decimal* integer 10:

```
~10
```

I expect it to compute bitwise NOT on the *binary* integer as follows:

```
~1010 = 0101
```

In otherwords, I expected decimal integer 5.  Instead, the operation gives me -11.  (try it in your console)

```
~10 = -11
```

If I check that more explicitly by looking at -11 and ~10 as binary integer strings:

```
parseInt(~10,10).toString(2)
"-1011"

parseInt(-11,10).toString(2)
"-1011"
```

Consistent.  But I don't understand.  Can anyone explain to me why?  I'm guessing that it is something to do with the sign.

EDIT:  [I found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12337360/3322676) after posting, it also helped me understand this phenomena much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitwise operators in Javascript treat the number as 32 bits. So 10 is

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00001010
```

When you invert it, the result is:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110101
```

When interpreted as a 32-bit signed number, that's -11 (if you don't understand why, read the Wikipedia entry on [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)).