# Why does Javascript treat a number as a two's complement

Tags: javascript, binary

Here is the explanation of why `~5` equals to `-6` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337360/javascript-tilde-twos-complement):

> 5               = 0000 0101
>
> Flipped (~5)    = 1111 1010
>
> So, which
>   number does 1111 1010 represent? Since the first digit is a 1 we know
>   it's a negative value. To find which value, do
>
> -(flip(1111 1010) + 1) =
>   -(0000 0101 + 1)
>   -(0000 0110) =
>   -6

I'm wondering why Javascript treats the result of the `~5` as a number in the two's complement form?

My confusion stems from the fact that if I write `0b11111010` in the console it evaluates to 250, not -6

Comment: Your question reduces to "why are integers signed in Javascript?".

Comment: My confusion stems from the fact that if I write `0b11111010` in the console it evaluates to 250, not -6

Comment: That's because integers aren't 8-bit.

Comment: Can you elaborate please a bit?

Comment: `5` is an integer that is, as Oliver pointed out, NOT 8 bit. `0b11111010`, on the other hand, is an 8 bit binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's how Javascript represents negative numbers in binary. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

> The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format. Two's complement format means that a number's negative counterpart (e.g. 5 vs. -5) is all the number's bits inverted (bitwise NOT of the number, a.k.a. ones' complement of the number) plus one.