# javascript convert number to utf-8

Tags: javascript

In C, I'd be able to do something like this:

```
short number = 20693; // Create the number
unsigned char* str = malloc(3); // Create the string
memcpy(str, &number, 2); // Copy the number to the string
str[2] = 0; // 0-pad it
```

And then `str` would contain the utf-8 representation of `number`. Is it possible to do this in javascript (without the 0-padding)?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939760/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-binary-in-javascript

Comment: Obviously it's possible, but your C example is **hilariously** irrelevant to a JavaScript solution.

Comment: @tymeJV, nope, that one wants to convert a number into a binary number (like 25 would become 11001), and I want the number to be, well, encoded in binary (like 65 would become "A")

Comment: @MiJyn Err, maybe take out the reference to "binary" then. You're looking for the ASCII number for a given character, this has **nothing** to do with binary.

Comment: @meagar, okay, but a quick note: it's not the ASCII number, it would be the UTF-8 number (which is what the C example does)

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate. they are two completely different questions. Which the answers are both different as you can see.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open. The question is not a duplicate, and the accepted answer is not correct - fromCharCode accepts UTF-16, not UTF-8. It's a shame to be googling the answer years after this was asked, and be blocked/delayed by a fake duplicate claim.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want `String.fromCharCode`...

```
String.fromCharCode(65);  // "A"
```

...which is the opposite of `String.charCodeAt`:

```
"A".charCodeAt(0); // 65
```