# Unexpected string when printing variable to console: [object Window]

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print text as binary value on console, but the result is "[object Window]".

```
console.log(toString(number, 2));
```

Comment: By binary value, do you mean the binary ascii value? (ex `a` = `01100001`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I convert an integer to binary in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939760/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-binary-in-javascript)

Comment: @Azeirah: I mean the binary representation of the number.

Answer (score 2):

Like most things in JS, `toString` is a method on the particular object, not a global function. [See this MDN page, with examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString).

So you want:

```
console.log(number.toString(2));
```

What is happening in your code is that it is liooking for some object to call `toString` on, and finding the "root object", which is `window`. So your code translates to this:

```
console.log(window.toString(number, 2));
```

Since `window.toString` doesn't take any arguments, they are ignored, meaning it's just like running this:

```
console.log(window.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

toString is a method, not a function. Since calling functions in javascript calls them from the window object, you get [object Window]

```
console.log(number.toString(2));
```

will convert a number into binary.

ex:

```
var num = 15;
console.log(num.toString(2));
> num = 1111;
```

Comment: So it was calling the wrong function, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, not exactly. It was calling the right function, but on the wrong context.

Comment: I think your console output is wrong. It should print 1111 instead of 15.