# How to load an Array (of numbers) into a google app script Byte[]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an Array (of numbers) in Google Apps Script, and I want to convert it to base64. I could of course use a simple open-source library such as [this one](https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js/blob/master/lib/b64.js).

However GAS already provides functions for this using [`Utilities.base64Encode(Byte[])`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Encode%28String%29)
but to call this function I need a `Byte[]` not `Number[]`.

Therefore the following script gives an error: (`Cannot convert Array to (class)[].`)

```
function testBase64Encode()
{
  var bytes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 255; i++) bytes.push(i);

  var x = Utilities.base64Encode(bytes)
}
```

Normally `Byte[]`'s come directly out of a Blob's `GetBytes()` function, however in my case the Array (of numbers) comes out of [zlib encryption lib](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js).

So I am trying to find a way to convert that Number Array to a `Byte[]`, acceptable for use with `Utilities.base64Encode(Byte[])`.

I did try to create a Byte myself and put them into an Array, however the following code also gives an error: (`ReferenceError: "Byte" is not defined.`)

```
var b1 = new Byte();
```

I did some more testing, and it seems to work as long as the value in the bytes' numeric values are 128 or lower. I find this weird because a byte should go up to 255.

The following code runs fine for 'bytes' but fails for 'bytes2' because there is a value greater than 128:

```
function testByteArrays()
{
  var bytes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 128; i++) bytes.push(i);
  var x = Utilities.newBlob(bytes)

  var bytes2 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 129; i++) bytes2.push(i);
  var x = Utilities.newBlob(bytes2)
}
```

Comment: basically what you are asking is convert an integer to binary? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939760/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-binary-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...a byte should go up to 255.

But not in [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) notation... in that case, the bytes should be in the range [-128..127], where the high-order bit is reserved as a sign bit. Given a positive integer `i`, we need to calculate the two's complement if it is greater than 127. That can be done by subtracting 2<sup>8</sup> (256). Applying that to your first example:

```
function testBase64Encode()
{
  var bytes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 255; i++) bytes.push(i<128?i:i-256);

  var x = Utilities.base64Encode(bytes)
}
```

This will avoid the error message you were receiving (`Cannot convert Array to (class)[].`). Ideally, you should also ensure that the number values start in the range 0..255.