# Base64 encode (byte) array in Google AppsScript?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, base64, byte

In Google AppsScript, I'm trying to [Base64 encode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64EncodeWebSafe(Byte)) a byte array using the `Utilities` class.

**UPDATE:** Example of this here: https://script.google.com/d/15eLqgLHExpLG64JZhjUzKfBj4DgLhNZGBOkjwz7AkeeUbcgcaraP4y9X/edit?usp=sharing

```
// bytes to encode
var toenc = [ 0x52 , 0x49 , 0x46 , 0x46 
        , 0xBC , 0xAF , 0x01 , 0x00 
        , 0x57 , 0x41 , 0x56 , 0x45 
        , 0x66 , 0x6D , 0x74 , 0x20 
        , 0x10 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 
        , 0x01 , 0x00 , 0x01 , 0x00 
        , 0x40 , 0x1f , 0x00 , 0x00 
        , 0x40 , 0x1f , 0x00 , 0x00 
        , 0x01 , 0x00 , 0x08 , 0x00 
        , 0x64 , 0x61 , 0x74 , 0x61 
        , 0x98 , 0xaf , 0x01 , 0x00
];

// This errs with -- Cannot convert Array to (class)[]
Logger.log(Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(toenc));

// OK, typing issue?  Following the doc, but still get same error :-(
Logger.log(Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(
  Utilities.newBlob(toenc).getBytes()
));
```

Alas, the very same error **Cannot convert Array to (class)[]** on run.

If I have an array of (byte) numbers (effectively a string), am I able to employ the `Utilities` class to Base64 it?

Comment: I can run this without any problems. The output is V0FWRWZtdCAQAAAAZGF0YQ==

Comment: That runs without error for you in AppsScript?

Comment: Yeah, i just wrapped it into a function to run it and it worked fine.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach, my apologies, I truncated my array for brevity in the code.  Alas, with the updated list of 44 bytes up there, it does not run.  Please see https://script.google.com/d/15eLqgLHExpLG64JZhjUzKfBj4DgLhNZGBOkjwz7AkeeUbcgcaraP4y9X/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  It deals with the fact the function wants a 2's compliment number.  Solution:

```
function to64(arr) {
  var bytes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    bytes.push(arr[i]<128?arr[i]:arr[i]-256);
  return Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(bytes)
} // to64
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639942/199305

Answer (score 1):

Is a following script helpful for you? If I have misread your question, I apologize.

```
var toenc = [ 0x57 , 0x41 , 0x56 , 0x45 
  , 0x66 , 0x6D , 0x74 , 0x20 
  , 0x10 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 
  , 0x64 , 0x61 , 0x74 , 0x61
];
var a1 = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(toenc);
var a2 = Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(a1, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
var a3 = Utilities.newBlob(a2).getDataAsString();

>>> a1 = V0FWRWZtdCAQAAAAZGF0YQ==
>>> a2 = [87, 65, 86, 69, 102, 109, 116, 32, 16, 0, 0, 0, 100, 97, 116, 97]
>>> a3 = WAVEfmt ���data
```

Comment: I'm at a total loss as to why I cannot run these in AppsScript.

Comment: Update:  Please see my update above.  For brevity, I made the array shorter.  It is now 44 and no longer working again.