# Is function computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key) broken?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, jwt

I am trying to sign the value `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6InRzIiwibm9uY2UiOiI4MTZkMWVmNi0zYjNlLTQ1MmEtOWM5Yi0xNDYyZWIzNWZlNzUiLCJpc3MiOiIwYzE3MjYwNDEwMjhkMTI5ZGI3YjU4NzUzYzU2OTYwYyIsImV4cCI6MTU4ODUyOTE3OCwibmJmIjoxNTg4NTI4ODE4LCJpYXQiOjE1ODg1Mjg4MTgsImp0aSI6IjE2ZGExZGZiLTkyYjQtNDI0ZS04ZTU5LWIyNzZmYmQ3MWVkYSIsInJlZ2lvbiI6Im55IiwibWV0aG9kIjoiR0VUIiwicGF0aCI6Ii9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGUvY29ubmVjdC9kZXZpY2UiLCJob3N0IjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkuYmxvb21iZXJnLmNvbSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IjBjMTcyNjA0MTAyOGQxMjlkYjdiNTg3NTNjNTY5NjBjIn0` with key `a1b2c3a4b5c6`. The key is hexadecimal.

This should generate signature `8Wspda1l2Z3-hLwvMI_5Q8AQic59oclZAav7kWVtGHw`. This signature is provided from my service provider as a sample.

I tried the following:

```
var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6InRzIiwibm9uY2UiOiI4MTZkMWVmNi0zYjNlLTQ1MmEtOWM5Yi0xNDYyZWIzNWZlNzUiLCJpc3MiOiIwYzE3MjYwNDEwMjhkMTI5ZGI3YjU4NzUzYzU2OTYwYyIsImV4cCI6MTU4ODUyOTE3OCwibmJmIjoxNTg4NTI4ODE4LCJpYXQiOjE1ODg1Mjg4MTgsImp0aSI6IjE2ZGExZGZiLTkyYjQtNDI0ZS04ZTU5LWIyNzZmYmQ3MWVkYSIsInJlZ2lvbiI6Im55IiwibWV0aG9kIjoiR0VUIiwicGF0aCI6Ii9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGUvY29ubmVjdC9kZXZpY2UiLCJob3N0IjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkuYmxvb21iZXJnLmNvbSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IjBjMTcyNjA0MTAyOGQxMjlkYjdiNTg3NTNjNTY5NjBjIn0", "a1b2c3a4b5c6");
var encodedSignature = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(signature).replace(/=+$/, '');
```

but I got different result: `vnshuAi4GtWTZ3VxmPgLzJ--V18mm-r4cBUNA0FIvTs`.

Since computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key) also allows input to be pair of byte[] (in addition to string pair as an input), I tried the following:

```
function toUTF8Array(str) {
    var utf8 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var charcode = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (charcode < 0x80) utf8.push(charcode);
        else if (charcode < 0x800) {
            utf8.push(0xc0 | (charcode >> 6),
                      0x80 | (charcode & 0x3f));
        }
        else if (charcode < 0xd800 || charcode >= 0xe000) {
            utf8.push(0xe0 | (charcode >> 12),
                      0x80 | ((charcode>>6) & 0x3f),
                      0x80 | (charcode & 0x3f));
        }
        // surrogate pair
        else {
            i++;
            // UTF-16 encodes 0x10000-0x10FFFF by
            // subtracting 0x10000 and splitting the
            // 20 bits of 0x0-0xFFFFF into two halves
            charcode = 0x10000 + (((charcode & 0x3ff)<<10)
                      | (str.charCodeAt(i) & 0x3ff));
            utf8.push(0xf0 | (charcode >>18),
                      0x80 | ((charcode>>12) & 0x3f),
                      0x80 | ((charcode>>6) & 0x3f),
                      0x80 | (charcode & 0x3f));
        }
    }
    return utf8;
} 

function resecret(s) {

  var bin_secret = "";
  var duo = ""
  var new_secret_array = [];
  var j = 0;
  var len=s.length;
  var element = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    duo = s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i+1);
    element = parseInt(duo, 16);
//    element = "0x"+duo;
    bin_secret = bin_secret + element;
    new_secret_array[j] = element;
    j++;
    i++;
  }
  return new_secret_array;
}

function test() {
var value="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6InRzIiwibm9uY2UiOiI4MTZkMWVmNi0zYjNlLTQ1MmEtOWM5Yi0xNDYyZWIzNWZlNzUiLCJpc3MiOiIwYzE3MjYwNDEwMjhkMTI5ZGI3YjU4NzUzYzU2OTYwYyIsImV4cCI6MTU4ODUyOTE3OCwibmJmIjoxNTg4NTI4ODE4LCJpYXQiOjE1ODg1Mjg4MTgsImp0aSI6IjE2ZGExZGZiLTkyYjQtNDI0ZS04ZTU5LWIyNzZmYmQ3MWVkYSIsInJlZ2lvbiI6Im55IiwibWV0aG9kIjoiR0VUIiwicGF0aCI6Ii9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGUvY29ubmVjdC9kZXZpY2UiLCJob3N0IjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hcGkuYmxvb21iZXJnLmNvbSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IjBjMTcyNjA0MTAyOGQxMjlkYjdiNTg3NTNjNTY5NjBjIn0";
var key = "a1b2c3a4b5c6";
var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(toUTF8Array(value),resecret(key));
}
```

This time, I get an error:

> Cannot convert Array to (class)[].

What am I doing wrong here? Has anyone able to run computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key) using byte array?

How do I get the signature `8Wspda1l2Z3-hLwvMI_5Q8AQic59oclZAav7kWVtGHw`?

Comment: You can get the correct byte array using `Utilities.newBlob(value).getBytes()`

Comment: In the case of `computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key)`, when the same `value, key` are used for the string type and the byte array type, the same result is returned. In your question, `computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key)` returns `be7b21b808b81ad59367757198f80bcc9fbe575f269beaf870150d034148bd3b` as HEX. Can I ask you about the detail logic for retrieving `8Wspda1l2Z3-hLwvMI_5Q8AQic59oclZAav7kWVtGHw` from the value by `computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key)`? In your case, `Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe` is used. Is it correct? Can you provide the specification for retrieving the signature?

Comment: @Tanaike - the service provider first takes secret and runs it through binascii.unhexlify() function then set it as variable key. Then it gets signed by following code found in api_jws.py in `import jwt`.

`segments.append(base64url_encode(json_header))
segments.append(base64url_encode(payload)) 
# Segments
        signing_input = b'.'.join(segments)
        try:
            alg_obj = self._algorithms[algorithm]
            key = alg_obj.prepare_key(key)
            signature = alg_obj.sign(signing_input, key)`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Can you explain about the detail of it and when you put the script, please add it to your question. Because it is difficult to see the script in the comment. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load an Array (of numbers) into a google app script Byte\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630661/how-to-load-an-array-of-numbers-into-a-google-app-script-byte)