# How does base 10 number to base 2 number conversion work?

Tags: javascript, theory, number-formatting

I'm trying to understand the following code, found in MDN and in an answer of this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939760/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-binary-in-javascript?lq=1). (Tested in FF 30 only.)

```
function createBinaryString (nMask) {
    // nMask must be between -2147483648 and 2147483647
    for (var nFlag = 0, nShifted = nMask, sMask = ""; nFlag < 32;
        nFlag++, sMask += String(nShifted >>> 31), nShifted <<= 1);
    return sMask;
}
var p = createBinaryString(7);
console.log(p); //"00000000000000000000000000000111"
```

This one is on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E%3E_%28Zero-fill_right_shift%29), but how does this work - I'd appreciate any understandable explanation.
I have basic knowledge of binary operators and know, that there is a `.toString(2)` method. But what does the `String(nShifted >>> 31)` part do exactly?

Here are better readable versions, but the first one does not work. Here I also would appreciate any suggestion about what I'm doing wrong. I can't see any difference to the second, working version.

```
var re = '';
var numb = 7;
var shiftBuf = numb;
for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++); {
   re += String(shiftBuf >>> 31);
   shiftBuf <<= 1;
}
console.log(re); //"0" 

var result = '';
var num = 7;
var shiftBuffer = num;
for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
   result += String(shiftBuffer >>> 31);
   shiftBuffer <<= 1;
}
console.log(result); //"00000000000000000000000000000111"
```

Comment: Rq : you have a ; ending your first for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important assumption here is that the initial number is less then 2^32. In that case it's just retrieving a digit after digit in binary representation.

```
re += String(shiftBuf >>> 31);
shiftBuf <<= 1;
```

The first line adds `shiftBuf` moved 31 places to the right to `re`, the second line moves `shiftBuf` to the left. So basically it just gets digits. Here's an example. If `shiftBuf = 7;` then in binary representation it is `111`. Add missing zeros and you have

```
00000000000000000000000000000111
```

Step by step:

```
[0] shiftBuf >>> 31 produces 0  // picks first digit if shiftBuf < 2^32
[0] result is now "0"
[0] shitBuffer <<= 1 produces 00000000000000000000000000001110

[1] shiftBuf >>> 31 produces 0
[1] result is now "00"
[1] shitBuffer <<= 1 produces 00000000000000000000000000011100

[2] shiftBuf >>> 31 produces 0
[2] result is now "000"
[2] shitBuffer <<= 1 produces 00000000000000000000000000111000

...

[30] shiftBuf >>> 31 produces 1
[30] result is now "0000000000000000000000000000011"
[30] shitBuffer <<= 1 produces 10000000000000000000000000000000

[31] shiftBuf >>> 31 produces 1
[31] result is now "00000000000000000000000000000111"
[31] shitBuffer <<= 1 produces 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

As for your second question: the difference between these two codes is that in the first one you have `for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++);` (note the semicolon at the end). The code that follows (the one in brackets `{}`) does not run in a loop. It runs only once.

Comment: I start to understand. So it goes from left to the right of the digital representation of the number. Shift operators always 'produce' 0 or 1? Why? Or is that the miracle of String(shiftBuf >>> 31)?

Comment: @malte Shift operators don't always produce 0 or 1. But if we are dealing with numbers less then 2^32 (i.e. 32 digit binary number) then shifting to the right 31 times leaves us with 1 digit: 0 or 1. So if a number is bigger then 2^32 then this algorithm won't work (well it wouldn't work because of another reason: binary and shift operators only work on integers up to 2^32).

Comment: Also shifting to the left only works for integers up to 2^32. From shifting operators point of view every number is a binary number with 32 digits (with leading zeros). Shifting to the left or right does not affect number of digits (just like in my example).