# get byte size of value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a value that is integral form, but I don't know if it is Uint8 or Uint16 or Uint32. Now I want to get byte size of it for example I want some thing like this:

```
var a = 100;     // 1100100
var b = 1000;    // 1111101000
console.log (byteSizeOf(a)); // --> 2
console.log (byteSizeOf(b)); // --> 3
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding ?

Comment: its's (signed) int32, that's an "optimization" that you can rely on nowadays, afaik. the spec defines all numbers in JS as doubles (64Bit floating point values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic math, if thats only decimal numbers you need to size:

```
Math.ceil(Math.log2(100)/4)
```

--> 2

```
Math.ceil(Math.log2(1000)/4)
```

--> 3

But you also have to handle spacial case of 0 and 1:

```
function byteSizeOf( x ) {
    return ( x < 2 )?1:Math.ceil(Math.log2(x)/4);
}
```

You can convert number to binary string like here:
[how do I convert an integer to binary in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939760/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-binary-in-javascript)

```
function dec2bin(dec){
    return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}
```

And then you can convert the result to binary array:

```
"110011".split().map(function(x){return parseInt(x);})
```

Comment: tanks for your answer but is it possible to get its binary data too? for example for 100 get '1100100'.

Comment: i  meant that we send 100 to function and it returns 1100100. and also not string( it should be number)

Comment: a number? js does not have binary numbers, so 1100100 will be interpreted as decimal. Meaning that it has to be represented as string.

Comment: no. in fact i mean binary array. sorry that i didn't mentioned it.like array buffer