# convert decimal to binary in jquery

Tags: jquery

am trying to convert a decimal number to binary in jquery but unable to

```
         var n = 5;
         var  i = 1;
         var rem = 0;
         var binary = 0;

    while (n!=0) 
     {
       rem= n % 2;
       n= n / 2;
       binary = binary + rem * i;
       i= i * 10;
   }
   alert(binary);
```

i have used the same formula for converting decimal to binary in other programming languages like `c++` and it works just fine but it gives an `infinity error` here

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kunz/pu28bvjg/)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939760/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-binary-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I convert an integer to binary in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939760/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-binary-in-javascript)

Comment: There is no decimal here. The input is already binary.

Answer (score 1):

After division converts it to integer otherwise it may lead to infinite loop since it won't reaches 0 in some case(number may contain decimal part).

```
n= parseInt(n / 2, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is

```
 n = n / 2;
```

because in JavaScript (jQuery) the division returns a float number, not an integer.

So you have first 2.5, then 1.25, 0.625, 0.3125, and so on, so your condition is not satisfied.

To avoid this you just need to parse to integer the float result

```
n = parseInt(n / 2);
```