# Javascript convert int "A" to "0xA" notation

Tags: javascript, binary, int

What is the best way to get from integer number A -> binary 0xA.

**Explanation on example:**

- I have [52, 49, 46] -> [00110100, 00110001, 00101110]
- I need [0x52, 0x49, 0x46] -> [82, 73, 70] -> [01010010, 01001001, 01000110]

My solution:

```
var arr = [52, 49, 46] 
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   arr[i] = parseInt("0x" + arr[i]);
}
```

Are there any other ways to do it?

Upgrade by Eric Dobbs:

```
arr = arr.map(x => parseInt(x, 16));
```

Comment: *"...from integer number A..."* What is an "integer number A"? *"... -> binary 0xA..."* What is a "binary 0xA"? (0x is a hex prefix). Are you confusing *representation* with *value*?

Comment: You can pass 16 as a second argument to parseInt: `arr = arr.map(x => parseInt(x, 16));`

Comment: `(52).toString(2)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939760/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-binary-in-javascript

Comment: Or better, be explicit about the base conversion: `parseInt(x.toString(10), 16)`. Of course you should probably just fix your data source to output the proper numbers (in the proper format, if they're literals) into that array from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a *number*, you can use `toString(2)` to get its representation (a *string*) in binary. Prepending a bunch of zeros and then using `.slice(-8)` will pad it out to eight digits. So for example:

```js
[52, 49, 46, 0x52, 0x49, 0x46].forEach(function(num) {
  console.log(("00000000" + num.toString(2)).slice(-8));
});
```

Comment: Rly that is not i need. I want to convert '52' in '0x52' like in example parseInt("0x" + 52);