# Trying to initialize a function by adding two numbers then transforming the sum into a binary string, what's missing?

Tags: javascript, function, binary, decimal

```
function addBinary(a,b) {
  var sum = a + b;
  return sum;

  function decToBin(sum) {
    return (sum >>> 0).toString(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have not called decToBin function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an integer to binary in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939760/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-binary-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
function addBinary(a,b) {
  var sum = a + b;

  //I added this line!
  //Instead of returning "sum", it returns output of "decToBin"
  return decToBin(sum);

  function decToBin(sum) {
    return (sum >>> 0).toString(2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
function addBinary(a,b) {
     var sum = a + b;
     return decToBin(sum);

     function decToBin(sum) {
         return dec2bin(sum);
     }
 }
```

or a shorter one like this.

```
function addBinary(a,b) {
    var sum = a + b;
    return dec2bin(sum);
}
```

You can also have negative numbers without a problem.