# Converting CIDR address from Hex to Binary in JS [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, networking, ip, trie, longest-prefix

I'm looking for a way to read a list of CIDR addresses and convert them into a binary strings.
The input is a file with rows of actions and addresses and destinations:

`ADD 192.168.20.16/28 A`

`FIND 255.255.255.0`

`REMOVE 192.168.20.16/28 A`

How can I convert these addresses to binary?
For example:

`192.168.20.191` to `11000000.10101000.00010100.10111111`

`192.168.20.16/28` to `11000000.10101000.00010100.00010000`

`192.168.0.0/16` to `11000000.10101000.00000000.00000000`

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939760/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-binary-in-javascript).

---

```js
function dec2bin(dec){
    return dec.toString(2);
}

const ips = ["192.168.20.191", "192.168.20.16", "192.168.0.0"]

ips.forEach((ip, index) => {
  const parts = ip.split(".")
  
  const newParts = []
  parts.forEach(part => {
    newParts.push(dec2bin(parseInt(part)))
  })
  
  ips[index] = newParts.join(".")
})

console.log(ips)
```

It's not perfect, because of zeros to the left, which are omitted, but you can improve this solution.

Comment: Yeah I've seen this solution, but I don't get how to convert CIDR notation
  to binary correctly.
>For example:192.168.20.16/28